# Django ratelimit custom function

Tags: django

how can I put a custom function for the method in django-ratelimit. I want it to be like this:

I filled out a form.

Then check if the length of the name is less than 5. If the length of the name is less than 5 then as many times as we fill the form it will never block the user. But if the length is bigger every time then the limiter will block the user.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do it without django-ratelimit

```
def rate_view(request):
    if request.method is "POST":
         name = request.POST["name"]
             if len(name) < 5:
                 #your logic 'with never block the user'
                 return render(request, "anyapp/any.html")
             elif len(name) > 5:
                 #block your user here
                 return render(request, "anyapp/any.html")
```

Comment: No I mean for example if the length of the name is more than 5 and then he fills the form over than 5 times then block.